# How do I capture the Months with proper Regex?

Tags: regex

How do I capture the days of months as numbers, excluding any suffixes. For instance - January 11th would be 11, and March 25th would be 25.

Comment: As specified in the regex tag, please specify what programming language or tool you are using, so we can provide an appropriate regex.

Comment: It's worth considering if there is an appropriate library you could use to parse the strings into datetimes, which would include validation that the date makes sense, etc.

Comment: What did you try and what about the attempt doesn't work? Is the rest of the input free text, or are these the only numbers in the input?

Comment: I am using Regex101 tried ((January-February-March-April-May-June-July-August-September-October-November-December)\d[1,2,3])

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex string and then only use the 3rd capturing group.
We accept 3 letter months Jan 1st and full name January 1st and accept space, hyphen,comma or slash as in Jan 01 Jan-01 Jan,1st Jan/31

```
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(uary|ruary|ch|il|e|y|ust|tember|ember)?[ \/,-]{0,2}([0-3]?[0-9])
```

You would do better to look for native time manipulation if possible.